# Use React Portals within the React-App (not outside the DOM)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement modals within my React app. Portals seems to be quite nice for this but I don't want to change my outer HTML-structure.

The HTML-should still be:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

I don't want to add an additional div to the HTML-structure.

In the App.js I tried to add the root-modal-container like this:

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ResponsiveProvider>
        <div id="root-modal"></div>
        <Modal>
           <div>Modal :-)</div>
        </Modal>
      </ResponsiveProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

But when trying to **getElementById** in the Modal-component I always get the error: appendChild on null...

The problem is, that the root-modal-div isn't renderend when initiating the Modal-component.

Any solutions how I can render Modals right in the level after  from anywhere in my app?

You can see the not-running-code [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMBdJW). Uncomment the second line in HTML to get the code running.

Comment: Please share all of the required code to reproduce what you would like to acheive

Comment: @Phillip You can see it here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMBdJW

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with React portals, but it's a little awkward, and you have to get quite involved with the DOM itself to render across an app like this (rather than to totally external DOM nodes).

I've just released a library to fix this exact problem, since although it's possible with portals, it's not easy.

You can see the full details at https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal.

In your example, a solution would look something like:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as portals from "react-reverse-portal";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Create a portal node: the link between the two ends of the portal
    this.modalNode = portals.createPortalNode();
  }

  render() {
    // Place an OutPortal somewhere: this is where the content will appear.
    // Could be many levels deep in your app - you just need to get the modalNode
    // there. For complex cases you might want to put it in a context to distribute it.
    return <div>
      <Child modalNode={this.modalNode} />
      <portals.OutPortal node={this.modalNode} />
    </div>;
  }
}

const Child = props => {
  // Place an InPortal somewhere: this is where the content is defined
  return <portals.InPortal node={props.modalNode}>
    <Modal>
      <div>Modal :-)</div>
    </Modal>
  </portals.InPortal>
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In the above: `Child` defines some modal content it wants to appear, and `App` defines the space where modal content should appear. You can use this to link parts of your app, and send rendered content between them. Hope that helps!